# Does Islam believe in rebirth?

Tags: belief, imaan

Most religions of the East believe in rebirth. Rebirth here means transmigration of soul from a dead body to a newborn body.

My question is :does Islam believe in rebirth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the name of God, the Most Merciful, the Most Kind.

The Lord Creator Declares in Truth in His Glorious Quran:

> ”We have brought you that each and every human being will be born only once from their mothers womb to this life for give a test”

So for a period of one life-time on this means that when earth; and every single human being will, without an iota of a person dies doubt, will remain dead till taste the day element of resurrection and then God will bring him back to death.

God Says in the Holy Quran Chapter 21 Surah Anbiyaa verse 35: 35:

> ”Every soul shall have a taste of death: and We test you by evil and by good (only) by way of trial: to Us must ye return.”

God says in the Holy Quran in Chapter 67 Surah Al Mulk verse 2:

> ”He (God) created death and life that He may test you, to see which of you is the best in deeds.”

When the test-period of one life is brought to stand an end through the element of death, the soul shall return back unto The Lord Creator, and on the Day of judgement the Lord Most High will raise and give life again to each and every individual to take a full accounting of their deeds.

The pagan concept of rebirth, whereby one is born again and again on earth until one reaches salvation is categorically denied and repudiated in Islam. So, Islam is against Reincarnation. If God wanted Reincarnation to be, then Islam would have support  Reincarnation but since God decided that Reincarnation should never take place nor to exist, then it has happened. This idea of Reincarnation is a fictional thing made up by Hindus.

If anyone believes in Reincarnation has committed a disbelief, because it goes against the commands of God.